# Chewy (Elasticsearch) - Multiple emails with uax_url_email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, chewy-gem

I have a simple email analyzer

```
analyzer: {
    email: {
      tokenizer: 'uax_url_email',
      filter: ['lowercase']
    }
  }
```

And a field with multiple email values:

```
  field :emails,
        type: :text,
        analyzer: 'email',
        search_analyzer: 'email',
        value: -> (user) { [user.email, user.lead_requests.pluck(:email)].flatten.compact.uniq }
```

After indexing it I tried to find it, I need to find it by part of email:

```
UsersIndex.query(wildcard: { emails: "*example.com" }).count
=> 1
```

But with @:

```
UsersIndex.query(wildcard: { emails: "*@example.com" }).count
=> 0
```

And wildcard not worked for full email:

```
UsersIndex.query(wildcard: { email: "volk@example.com" }).count
=> 0
```

Only match can find it with full value:

```
UsersIndex.query(match: { emails: "volk@example.com" }).count
=> 1
```

Seems uax_url_email not worked for it as expected.

What should I do with it to make contains search working?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing some mistake with the field or index name, its working for me, it would be better if you can provide the data in JSON format like below to confirm

**Index mapping and setting**

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "email": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "uax_url_email",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings" : {
        "properties" : {
            "mail" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "analyzer" : "email",
                "search_analyzer": "email"

            },
            "mail_keyword": {
                "type" : "keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Index sample data

```
{
    "mail" : "abd@example.com"
}
```

**Wildcard search query**

```
{
    "query" : {
        "wildcard" : {
            "mail" : "abd@example.com" (note exact same mail which I indexed)
        }
    }
}
```

**And search result**

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "wildcard_test",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "mail": "abd@example.com"
                }
            }
```